# Можно ли забанить пользователя в Телеграм в боте, а потом разбанить через определенное время?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, pyrogram

Есть чат-бот, в который приходят заявки 7 дней в неделю. Люди, что обрабатывают заявки, работают 1/3, 1 день рабочий (полные сутки) с 07.00, 25.05.22 по 07.00 26.05.22, потом 3 дня не работают, и снова выходят на смену.

Я не хочу тогда, когда сотрудник 3 дня отдыхает, видел сообщения по заявкам от бота или принимал их.

И сделать это циклом для всех сотрудников.

Есть метод, возможно через **/ban {userid}** - но он банит полностью.
а **$un_ban_params** - разбанивает...
Пытался вычислить функцию и как-то адаптировать отложенный постинг между ними (понимаю что бред, но вдруг), не сработало..

Comment: посмотрел pyrogram - вот такое решение, право пока не нашел, как его отредактировать так, что бы применить в боте

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Ban chat member forever
await app.ban_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)

# Ban chat member and automatically unban after 24h
await app.ban_chat_member(chat_id, user_id, datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))